# Clangd Struct Preview Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang, clangd

I am using [clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) vscode extension on a project and everything is working like a charm.

But I have an 'OCD Like' configuration I would like to configure.

I have the following struct definition:

[image: clangd preview]

Is there a way to change how clangd shows the preview index?
I would like it to show with two digits `[00], [01]` instead of one `[0], [1]` on lines 10 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current option to configure formatting the designator hints like this.

You could file an issue at https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues proposing to add one.

Comment: That's what I've assumed. Thank you.